# Reading data using tabula-py returns error

Tags: python, tabula

I am trying to read data from tabula-py but it returns an error and I'm not sure how to fix it. My current code consists of the three lines below

`import tabula`

`df = tabula.read_pdf("data.pdf", pages="all")`

`print(df)`

I am currently using terminal on MacOS to run my program. The terminal output is attached to this question.[image: error output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime. So you just need to update your JDK version, possible to JDK 7.

If you are running on Mac OS X you may have Apple java 6 and Oracle java 7. Try to compile with JDK7 and run with JDK6.